# How to say "lanzar serpentina" in english?

Tags: translation

Is it to launch serpentine?

This is what I mean. When a person lanches serpentine.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=krzBwKbuD44

Answer (score 3):

These tightly coiled ribbons of paper or foil are called "streamers" or "party streamers". There's no fixed term for "launching" them; in my experience they are more often thrown than blown out, and we'd just use one of those verbs.

Comment: We can **pop** some streamers.

Comment: This is probably from Brazil where during Carnaval, people let loose with them. It's hard to describe but it goes like this: There are coiled into a tight round circle. You hold them in  your hand with your forefinger facing in the "wind up" direction, and then you lift up  your finger and throw them using the same movement as throwing a ball straight in front of you so they unfurl. I would use: unfurling.